# Quake d_draw.s versus d_draw16.s

Tags: software-rendering

I decided to write my first Quake source port, but I'm a bit confused.

There are 2 rasterization code files: d_draw.s and d_draw16.s.

The first is, as John Carmack said, horizontal 8-bpp span-drawing code. The second is the same, but with 16-pixel subdivision.

Which is more preferable for full-color 320x200 source port?

Do they both feature non-power-of-2 texture distortion?

GL code is not an option, because the target system doesn't feature 3D API.

Comment: http://reocities.com/ResearchTriangle/4480/quake/quakecom.html#d_subdiv16

Comment: Thank you! Could you rewrite this in answers so I can give you some more points and close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [here](http://reocities.com/ResearchTriangle/4480/quake/quakecom.html#d_subdiv16)

> For maximum speed, perspective correction is performed only every 16
>   pixels.  This is normally fine, but it is possible to see texture ripples
>   in surfaces that are viewed at sharp angles.  For more precise texture
>   mapping, set the console variable d_subdiv16 to 0.  Doing this will result
>   in somewhat slower performance, however, and the difference in visual
>   quality will not normally be noticeable.

So I'm assuming for maximum visual quality you want d_draw and not d_draw16.